# Java compareTo() undefined operator

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write code that compares the marks of two report cards but everytime I use an operator like > or < it says it's undefined for the argument type. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit (from comments):** The type of `marks` and `getMarks` is `double[]`.

```
 * @param other
 * @return 1 if the average mark of calling object is more than average of parameter object
 * -1 if the average mark of calling object is less than average of parameter object
 * 0 if the average mark of calling object and the average of parameter object are the same
 */
public int compareTo(ReportCard other) {

    if(this.marks > other.getMarks()) {
        return 1;
        } else if (this.marks < other.getMarks()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } //to be completed
```

Comment: What type is `marks`?

Comment: marks is double type

Comment: And `getMarks()` also returns `double`?

Comment: yes getMarks() returns double aswell

Comment: Then you should `return Double.compare(this.marks, other.getMarks())`.

Comment: Are you sure `other` isn't null?

Comment: If it was `double` this wouldn't happen. Are you sure it's not `double[]`?

Comment: oh it is double[], my bad I didn't realise it would make a difference

Comment: Can you post the entire class? there is too much guessing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` are only available for primitive numeric types (`double`,`int`,`char` etc.).

The type `double []` is not a primitive type. It's an array type (which is an object). You have to devise your own way of comparing an array and write a loop for it.

Consider: what will you do if the current report card has 3 marks, and the other report card has 5 marks? Suppose the first three marks are the same. Which report card should be considered the greater?

If they have the same number of marks, then your loop should be something like (pseudocode):

```
For each element marks[i] in the current report card marks
    if it is greater than the other report card's mark at the same position
        return 1;
    else if it is less than the other report card's mark at the same position
        return -1;
end of loop
Return zero (the two arrays were exactly the same)
```

You need to expand this to consider the case when the arrays are not of the same length.

Note that this gives most significance to the first mark. If all marks are equally important, you may want to do something else, like comparing the mark averages or sums.

To sum up: you were trying to compare non-primitive values using the comparison operators. The operators are not defined for objects and array types and you have to write your own implementation that does this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

your code can be simplified to:

```
public int compareTo(ReportCard other) {
    return Double.compare(this.getMarks(), other.getMarks());
}
```

Or, if you want to create a `Comparator<ReportCard>` rather than implementing `Comparable<ReportCard>`, then you can do something like this:

```
Comparator<ReportCard> comparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(ReportCard::getMarks);
```

Comment: Even better, `Comparator.comparingDouble(ReportCard::getMarks)`.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are not fulfilling the asker’s requirements. `Double.compare()` returns “the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2”, so it’s not guaranteed to give 1, -1 or 0. No one using `compareTo()` ought to rely on those precise numbers, though.

Comment: @OleV.V. agreed. Strictly speaking, the OP misunderstood the Comparable / Comparator contract

Comment: Strictly speaking, the OP problem was that the operator `>` could not be applied to the value, which implies it is not a double at all...